# Limit points of the following sets?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Consider $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric $(|x-y|)$. Write down the limit points of the following sets.
[image]

I wrote:

$[0,1]$

$[-\sqrt2,\sqrt2]$

$[0,1]$

$[0,1]$

$\{1/n:n \geq 1\} \cup\{0\}$

$\{\sqrt2-1/n:n \geq 1\} \cup\{\sqrt 2\}$

Are these correct?

My definition of a limit point is: $x$ is a limit point of a set $A$ if all neighbourhoods of $x$ intersect $A-\{x\}$.

Comment: Yes of course thanks!

Comment: The last two are closures;  they are not the set of limit points.  Why is 1/2 a limit pt. of { 1/n  :  n in N }?   Consider 1/2 in (1/4, 1/3).

Comment: Remember that the definition of limit point does not consider the point itself, then answer the question by William Elliot.

Comment: So would the last two be just $0$ and then $\sqrt2$ then?